# Как организовать взаимодействие 2 пользователей в реальном времени?

Tags: ajax, php

Как можно связать 2 пользователей (брать их данные из БД) и показывать их друг другу в реальном времени?

Например:
бой с другом со случайным уроном (из БД брать жизни).

Comment: лучше не на php, иначе будете тыщу запросов посылать.

Comment: А на чём, не посоветуете ?

Comment: Вообще можно организовать на Демонах, лучше конечно на node.js поднять подобное

Comment: Будет свободное время - подумаю, радует, что такое реализуемо )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.IO и иже с ними в помощ.